# rsync vs fs.readStream - How to handle special characters

Tags: node.js, postgresql, utf-8, special-characters, rsync

I'm using two approaches to backing up a database file, rsync and a server-based API approach.

I'm getting slightly different results because of some particular certain high-numbered unicode characters, so the two backups are just a little bit different.

The characters in question are, in one case ⸭ (a unicode 2E2D), 猄 (unicode 7304), 璣 (74a3) which makes the voyage just fine through rsync, but which all become �� (two unicode FFFD characters) using the server / API approach.

Interestingly not all higher-numbered unicode characters get transformed to FFFDs.  A 䋲 (42F2), a 0698, and thousands of others that are not converted and make it through just fine.

In fact there are only about 7 characters in the entire file that get transformed in transit.

I'm trying to get this to the point where there no difference whatsoever.

Basically there's an occasional discrepancy handling high-numbered unicode.

In both cases the backup files created are utf8 with char(10) line feeds.

Here's the basic difference between the two backup approaches:

RSYNC APPROACH

`rsync -avuP path/to/server/ActiveDb.sql path/to/Backup.sql`

SERVER APPROACH

````
ThisStream=Fs.createReadStream("/path/to/ActiveDb.sql");
ThisStream.on("open", ()=>{
    ThisStream.pipe(Rr.Res);
});

On the backup machine
spawn=require("child_process").spawn("curl", ["-d", "apicall=bkup", "https://dbserver.server"]);
spawn.stdout.on("data", thisChunk=>{
    Fs.appendFileSync("path/to/Backup.sql", thisChunk);
});```
````

Comment: Using `curl` as a http(s) client in a node.js script is really weird. Also don't use `appendFileSync` - just open a write stream?

Comment: What is `Rr.Res`?

Comment: Thanks Berg. Ordinarily I'd expect `fs.writeStream` to be the better approach.  But in this context, so far at least, the results are not great: every file created using that method turns out different results, and there are a huge number of differences between each other and the original file.  In other words each download is different from the original, and from each other.  No idea why yet.  I might blame the cURL call, but...

Comment: ...`fs.appendFile` creates the same exact file, reliably every time.  All downloads match either other exactly.  There are these 7 characters of difference between the original and the downloaded, but the rest of the file is a perfect match.

Comment: Re Rr.Res  -- that's a bit of idiosyncratic code I should have cleaned up for clarity.  Thanks for catching it.  It's just "res" from standard node.js server as in `http.createServer((req, res) => {etc. etc.}`  In other words what's going on is there is a Node.js server which resides on a machine holding a sql database to be backed up and downloaded.  Then on the backup machine there a JS script that makes the request to the server and receives the downloads from the server.

Comment: Re cURL calls in a node context --  I use all the time to child_process.exec or spawn interactions with APIs of all kinds.  I personally prefer automating CLI in JS to coding command line directly.  For my taste JS had more articulate control for iteration and command line tends to offer more options.  I'm curious why for you it's weird?